# Grails doesn't use my data source when running in production or test?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, grails, groovy

Note that I'm using Grails 2.0.0 Milestone 2.

I'm getting the Hibernate error `createQuery is not valid without active transaction` when I try to WAR/deploy my Grails app or run the app using `prod run-app`/`test run-app`.  **If I use just plain `run-app`, everything works as expected.**

I'm wondering, what could possibly be different between `prod run-app` and `war` that would cause my data source to not be wired up correctly?

Here is my `DataSource.groovy` file:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "none" 
    url = "jdbc:mysql://something/mydb"
    pooled = true
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    username = "xxxxxx"
    password = "xxxxxxxxx"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}

hibernate {
    config.location = "classpath:some/hibernate/file.cfg.xml"
}
```

And, I have a service like so:

```
package org.dostuff

import org.dostuff.DaoFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

class StuffService {

    static transactional = true;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    def getSomething() {
        def daoFactory = new DaoFactory();
        def stuff = daoFactory.getSomeDao().getSomething();

        return stuff;
    }
}
```

Note that I inject the Hibernate `SessionFactory` statically into my `DaoFactory` in the `BootStrap.groovy` file.

What else could I be doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

As you can see in my question, I was loading my hibernate config file using the following:

```
hibernate {
    config.location = "classpath:some/hibernate/file.cfg.xml"
}
```

In my `file.cfg.xml`, I was defining a few properties... one of which was `current_session_context_class`

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

It turns out when I was doing `prod run-app` or `test run-app`, Grails was obeying that property I had in my config file, but when using just `run-app`, it was not for some reason.

So, if you run into this issue, be sure your hibernate config file doesn't have a setting which may interfere with how Grails manages Hibernate sessions!

Answer (score 1):

I see that Configuration tutorial does say 
"The previous example configuration assumes you want the same config for all environments: production, test, development etc."
But why dont you try configuring environments like following in your datasource.grrovy!

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:devDB"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:prodDb;shutdown=true"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that out as well, and still no luck.  It simply looks like it is ignoring my dataSource definition in production/test/war :(

Comment: Can you try creating a simple Domain class with a scaffolded controller and see if that works or not? This way you can figure out if your problem lays in the datasource.groovy or is it in the service itself